# Count dates based on a condition

Tags: excel

I would like to count the number of dates in January,I have a spreadsheet like the image below
[image]

I noticed that the end date is not counted and I would like to understand why, because I correctly defined the conditions: =CONT.SES(G:G;">="&A4;G:G;"<="&A5)
I have a table with dates formatted in Latin America as DD/MM/YYYY

Comment: Could the dates also hold time values? In that case 1 minute past midnight 31/01/2023 is greater than 31/01/2023 (00:00:00). You could use `"<"&A5+1` (smaller than 1 day after the end day)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an easy to use formula:

```
O365: =SUM(IF(MONTH(G2:G23)=1,1))

Non-O365: =SUMPRODUCT(IF(MONTH(G2:G23)=1,1))
```

Comment: You could change IF to N to be it a bit less verbose: =SUM(N(MONTH(G2:G23)=1)) . Also any other year or even empty cell could give false positive (it is not the case with given OP's sample data)

Comment: I like N trick.  I thought about the multi-year months, but the data shows only 2023, so I figured it was enough for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that u are using =COUNTIFS(G:G,">="&A4,G:G,"<="&A5) it should work correctly and show 5 as result.
check the dates by formatting them as numbers.